# creating a 'survival' dummy in R (panel data)

Tags: r, dummy-variable, panel-data

I would like to create a dummy that will be equal to 0 if the firm did not close next year (in this case I close means it was not recorded in the next time period ) in my unbalanced panel and 1 otherwise.

My data look like this:

```
firm_id year 
1        90  
1        92
2        90
2        92
2        94
2        96
3        90
```

So my desired output would look like:

```
firm_id year dummy
1        90   1
1        92   0
2        90   1
2        92   1
2        94   1
2        96   1
3        90   0
```

I am unsure of how to approach this problem, my original idea was to count the number of years associated with each firm firm_id and then if firm has 4 years assign it always 1, if firm had 3 years assign the first 2 years 1 and 3rd year 0, but then I discovered I had firms that entered the panel later so this method will not work. Is there some better approach that would solve this issue?

Comment: Firm id  = 2 never closed (there is no 0 for it) ? How would you know that looking at the data?

Comment: @RonakShah oh sorry, I think better way would be to say I want to put 0 for firms for which I know they did closed I edited the question

Comment: Do you mean you already know that firm_id 1 and 3 are closed and 2 is not? Do you have a list saved somewhere?

Comment: @RonakShah no but in the panel I work with firms drop out only when they close so if a firm was there in 92 but not in 94 I count it as closing in 92

Comment: So firm id 2 has no dummy  = 0 because there is no year value which is greater than 96?

Comment: @RonakShah its bit more complex, here I want to check if the firm is there next year. So if firm is there in 92 but not 94 in 92 it gets zero, but in the dataset I have only 4 years 90, 92, 94, 96 I do not want to set all firms in 96 to zero just because dataset ends, so if firm is there in 96 it gets automatically 1 (actually such firm get 1 everywhere, and that's one part I can easily create dummy for but the other cases I am clueless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value 0 to `dummy` if it is last entry of the firm id and it is not equal to max value of the year.

```
df$dummy <- 1
df$dummy[!duplicated(df$firm_id, fromLast = TRUE) & df$year != max(df$year)] <- 0
df

#  firm_id year dummy
#1       1   90     1
#2       1   92     0
#3       2   90     1
#4       2   92     1
#5       2   94     1
#6       2   96     1
#7       3   90     0
```

This requires your data to be sorted by year like in the example. If it is not sorted you can use `order` to sort them first.

```
df <- df[with(df, order(firm_id, year)), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(firm_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), year = c(90L, 
92L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 96L, 90L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: perfect, thanks such a simple solution, I was seriously overthinking it

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(dummy = +(duplicated(firm_id, fromLast = TRUE) | year == max(year)))
  firm_id year dummy
1       1   90     1
2       1   92     0
3       2   90     1
4       2   92     1
5       2   94     1
6       2   96     1
7       3   90     0
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(firm_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), year = c(90L, 
92L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 96L, 90L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```